# Is there a powerful yet lightweight vim-like keyboard-centric web browser out there (for Linux)?

Tags: linux, browser

I love Pentadactyl (previously Vimperator) for Firefox, but with all these plugins and things, Firefox is really slow. I've tried Vimium, but it's a little awkward and doesn't do all I'd like it to. I've also been playing around with Luakit, because it's in the Ubuntu repositories, and it's fast, lightweight, and has many of the same keybindings. However, I find Luakit doesn't do some of the things Pentadacytl can do.

I'm not a programmer, so I'm a little daunted by having to learn, say, Lua just so I can use a keyboard-centric web browser. Can someone recommend a feature-rich web browser that is still somewhat lightweight (i.e. won't take 10 seconds to start up on my laptop) and yet is not that difficult to configure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some to try:

- [jumanji](http://pwmt.org/projects/jumanji/).
- [Vimprobable](https://sourceforge.net/p/vimprobable/wiki/Home/)
- [dwb](http://portix.bitbucket.org/dwb/)
- [luakit](https://luakit.github.io)

Comment: Also try luakit: http://mason-larobina.github.io/luakit

Comment: *Luakit* seems dead now, and constantly crashes on my computer. *Jumanji* doesn't really seem to work either. I think *dwb* is the way to go.

Comment: There's also [vimb](https://fanglingsu.github.io/vimb/).

Comment: qutebrowser is my favourite. http://www.qutebrowser.org

Comment: +1 qutebrowser fits your description precisely (posted via qutebrowser :))

Answer (score 4):

There's `uzbl`. It follows well the UNIX philosophy, and it's very slim. If you're looking for lightweight and extremely functional, this is it.

Answer (score 2):

[Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) is probably the most keyboard-oriented graphical browser I have seen.  Apparently it even [supports some Firefox extensions](http://conkeror.org/Extensions).  I've never used it myself as it takes a while to learn the keybindings, but maybe you will like it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Opera yet?  When you install it go into the settings and enable UNIX Keyboard shortcuts.  Things like ^U work, you can tab through links on the page and select them.  They even have a page dedicated to how to use the browser without a mouse:

http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/nomouse/